# " a university has hectic schedules" or "universities have hectic schedules"?

Tags: indefinite-article

I think in order to describe a general situation, both the plural of countable noun and adding indefinite articles before the countable noun could work.

So is it ok for me to use both to convey the meaning that the general universities have hectic schedules?

> A university has hectic schedules"

or

> Universities have hectic schedules"?

However, I don't think the first one is quite right.

Comment: For a general statement, use the plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/schedule) defines a schedule as

> A list of planned activities or things to be done showing the times or dates when they are intended to happen or be done

When talking about a single organization like a University, unless you have a specific reason to describe it otherwise, you would probably say that it had a single schedule- a giant timetable covering the whole university. You would therefore say.

> A university has a hectic schedule.